# not able to install weblogic using chef script

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

We are trying to execute weblogic recipe from chef server on target node where chef client is installed. But weblogic is failing to install with the following error.

```
vsvphxfqa01.abc.com     Errno::ENOENT
vsvphxfqa01.abc.com     -------------
vsvphxfqa01.abc.com     No such file or directory - java -jar /tmp/wls1036_generic.jar -mode=silent -silent_xml=/tmp/wls-silent-install.xml -silent_log=/tmp/chef_install_weblogic.log
```

When we try to execute the same command under /tmp in chef client node, it is getting installed. Not sure why it is not happening from chef server.

Here is the recipe

```
vsvphxfqa01.abc.com       9:   execute "install_wls" do
vsvphxfqa01.abc.com      10:     user "#{node['weblogic']['UNIX_USER']}"
vsvphxfqa01.abc.com      11:     group "#{node['weblogic']['UNIX_GROUP']}"
vsvphxfqa01.abc.com      12:     cwd   "/opt/weblogic/java/jdk1.6.0_31"
vsvphxfqa01.abc.com      13:     command "java -jar #{temp}/wls1036_generic.jar -mode=silent -silent_xml=#{temp}/wls-silent-install.xml -silent_log=#{temp}/chef_install_weblogic.log"
vsvphxfqa01.abc.com      14:   end
vsvphxfqa01.abc.com      15: end
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't have java installed on that machine or java is not in PATH. PATH variable for Chef and your own user are different.

Comment: Java is installed under weblogic user. Once I login as weblogic, command which java works. But when i login as any user other than weblogic it says no java found. I don't know why chef is not using java which is set for weblogic. Do you mean we need to install java outside of /home/weblogic/ ?

Comment: You should add java location to PATH variable for Chef user.

Comment: I already added java to PATH variable for weblogic since we are executing  the scripts with this user only. Do you mean weblogic is not user used by chef?

Comment: Of course. Chef most probably runs as root.

Comment: Thanks. We have did softlink of Java home to /usr/bin and then it worked. Let me know how can i mark your comment as answered.